# Excel VBA - COPY COLUMN / Paste based upon column A

Tags: vba, excel

I have the values in

```
Column A 
1001-3000
1002-3000
1003-3000
```

I have dates respectively in

```
Column B
12/1/2017
12/2/2017
12/3/2017
```

I am currently running a report that extract the data and makes it it so Column A can appear once or multiple times;

```
Column A
1001-3000
1002-3000
1002-3000
1003-3000
1003-3000
1003-3000
```

The dates in Column B are still reflective of Column A, but I am trying to mirror the date to the data in Column A

```
Output
1001-3000 12/1/2017
1002-3000 12/2/2017
1002-3000 12/2/2017
1003-3000 12/3/2017
1003-3000 12/3/2017
1003-3000 12/3/2017
```

I currently have the code

```
Dim iv As Long

Workbooks("SourceReport.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("SourceReport").Select
iv = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("BG2:BG" & iv).Copy

Workbooks("TargetReport.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Range("G2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'esp
```

used to copy the entire column from one Workbook to another. This however doesnt work with the data listed as it just moves all data directly into the column.

Comment: What is the relationship between Column A and Column B? Can you say that 1001-3000 matches to 12/1/2017 and 1002-3000 matches to 12/2/2017?  What happens when you get to the next month?  does 1/1/2018 match 1032-3000? Could you use Column A to calculate the date?

Comment: If i understand correctly `vlookup` will be handy. either in direct formula or through vba code to match codes in col A with dates in col B (assuming unique dates / codes are listed in some other sheet).

Comment: Column A is directly related to Column B

The date is variable as is the data in Column B, but always relational.

Comment: you would never not know the date, the date in Column B is always given with the Data in Column A. Its getting the date to appear for each occurrence of the data in Column A.

Comment: Use `VLOOKUP` to reference the original A and B columns, it's tailor made for this purpose unless I'm not understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: I will look into inserting VLOOKUP into this code. I assume an if statement would be required.

Yes the data for Column A and B is always present on another sheet.

Comment: Scott, thank you. I was able to figure out the formula I needed for that column pretty easily after that suggestion.

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Shippingorderreport.xlsx!$A$1:$BG$500,59,FALSE),"")